# OpenSea Error - Please use providerUtils.standardizeOrThrow()

Tags: javascript, node.js, opensea

I'm having trouble using the [openseas.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opensea-js) library. I'm trying to do a getAsset call on a random asset on openseas I found, but I keep getting

Error: `DEPRECATED: Please use providerUtils.standardizeOrThrow() instead supportedProvider.send.toString(...).replaceAll is not a function`

Full Error:
[image]

I'm currently on node v16.14.2.

How can I resolve this issue? I appreciate the help!

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
import { OpenSeaPort, Network } from "opensea-js";
import { OpenSeaAsset } from "opensea-js/lib/types";

// This example provider won't let you make transactions, only read-only calls:
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io");

const seaport = new OpenSeaPort(provider, {
  networkName: Network.Main,
});

(async function main() {
  try {
    //random asset I found on OpenSea
    const asset: OpenSeaAsset = await seaport.api.getAsset({
      tokenAddress: "0x20ed6cdf9344b3a187063a3ff4d883b6b1947b81", // string
      tokenId: 220, // string | number | null
    });
    console.log("Asset", asset);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR", e);
  }
});
```

```
  "dependencies": {
    "opensea-js": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web3": "^1.7.3",
    "web3-provider-engine": "^16.0.3"
  }
```

Comment: What version of opensea-js, and why mix import with require?

Comment: I tried it as a .js and .ts file just for kicks and was messing around with imports, but that doesn't really make a difference. I just posted dependency versions above.

Comment: Did you post this same question [here](https://serveanswer.com/questions/please-use-providerutils-standardizeorthrow-opensea-error)?

Comment: @ArnavThorat I didn't post there. That was probably scraped

Comment: Oh, okay. It looks the exact same. 

Comment: I'm guessing it is, but a bot did it.    ```¯\_(ツ)_/¯```

Comment: Oh, okay. The bot probably either wanted to find an answer for you over there on the help website, or it was just an auto-bot.

Comment: Check the answers on the other website (in general) - most are probably scraped from SO as well.  There are plenty of such sites, monetizing SO content with their own ads.

Answer (score -1):

First, check the obvious things—since I know these bite me from time to time—clear your `node_modules` and reinstall, make sure your `package-lock.json` matches the versions you expect from `package.json`, make sure you're not running from a previous build, etc...

My guess is that something in your project is importing/using old versions of some of the `0xProject` libs. Run `npm list --all` and see which ones are imported.

Worst case: that error is coming from the `isWeb3Provider` function [in the 0xProject/assert project](https://github.com/0xProject/tools/blob/1eec1e081f73258aa42a96f530df76292d6d586d/assert/src/index.ts#L78) -- `grep -r` in your `node_modules` for something calling `isWeb3Provider`. Hopefully that'll give a clue.

Comment: I tried reinstalling deleting and reinstalling node_modules, but that didn't work. Also don't have imported versions per ```npm list --all```. I did add a full screenshot above with a little more detail. Didn't mean to leave that out, but it also says ```supportedProvider.send.toString(...).replaceAll is not a function```. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?